# How can I fetch List + Hashmap to C++ code through JNI

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, java-native-interface

I'm working on some special project.

I want get Android Contact data on C++ through JNI

Here is my JAVA side code. (Fetch Android contact database)

```
//For Map, HashMap, List 
Map map;
List list = new ArrayList();
.
.
//add values into Hashmap
map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", name);
map.put("email", email);
.
.
// Gather Contact data and add a list
list.add(map);
.
// return List+Hashmap data
return list;
```

Could you suggest or give a example this scenario about How can I get or fetch a List+Hashmap type data in C++ side?

I think JNI "GetObjectArrayElement" function will resolve this issue.
but GetObjectArrayElement is just only fetch 1-d array.

Comment: Do you need more help? Do you need that I elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You will pass an objet to JNI, "list", of class "ArrayList". You will then use the methods of ArrayList, eg "get", which will return objects of class "HashMap". No array operation here (except if you use "toArray" in Java or in JNI)